# Play! Framework Access a Play variable from Javascript

Tags: javascript, playframework, global-variables

I'm new to the Play framework (1.2) but I was wondering and hopefully I phrase this question correctly....I have a Play variable which stores which section ("_section") of a page the user is currently viewing. Is there any way to access that variable from a .js function?

UPDATE:

```
You can store objects for js as well from play:


    <script type="text/javascript">
          window.mytestarray = new Array();
     </script>



       #{list 0..links.size()-1, as:'i'}



   {%
    router = play.mvc.Router;
    url = router.reverse(_section + '.' + links[i]).url;
   %}


      <script  type="text/javascript">
           window.mytestarray.push("${url}")
      </script>


   <li js_sub_nav_name="${ _section}" >  <!-- MC class="#{if i == 0}first#{/if}"-->
   <a href="${url}" class="${lines[i]}#{if _page == links[i]} active#{/if}">&{'header.nav.'+_section+'.'+links[i]+'.html'}</a>

   </li>
  #{/list}
  </ul>
 #{/if}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a javascript global variable inside your view file, and access that variable from other javascript files:

```
#my view
...
<script type="text/javascript>
window._section = "${_section}";
</script>
```

Then from within a javascript file:

```
if (_section == ...)
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I was trying to do! Just one thing; there is a syntax error in your code: should be:  <script type="text/javascript">    (Missing " at end of 'javascript')

Comment: Also can you access local play variables and objects as well?  For instance in this play code can I store 'router' and 'url' for later reference in Javascript?                                                              #{list  #{list 0..links.size()-1, as:'i'}
   {%
    router = play.mvc.Router;
    url = router.reverse(_section + '.' + links[i]).url;
   %}

Comment: One more thing: if _section is updated in play code then the corresponding js variable is not updated...any way around that?

Comment: Found you can store objects --- in an array for example:                     {%
    router = play.mvc.Router;
    url = router.reverse(_section + '.' + links[i]).url;
   %}
   
   
      <script  type="text/javascript">
           window.mytestarray.push("${url}")
      </script>
   
   
   <li js_sub_nav_name="${ _section}"

Answer (score 3):

Use html5 data attributes, like:

```
<div id="yourSection" data-section="${_section}">
...your section contents...
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance you can store an object in data-section and not just a string?

Comment: if you stretch it a bit, you could maybe store a json string that you can convert easily to a javascript object, or if you stretch it a bit more, you can serialize your object however you want and have a javascript version to deserialize it. I've never needed to do anything like that.